# KDB+ Node.js interface

Tags: node.js, kdb

Has anyone come across a Node.js kdb interface? I want to use node as feed handler to my tickerplant. So far I have only seen the languages listed on the kx wiki:

http://code.kx.com/wiki/Cookbook#kdb.2B_foreign_language_interfacing

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do it through websockets. Create a websocket server on your node.js platform by using the ws package and connect it to the port of your kdb server.

```
require('ws').Server
```

[Here's](http://www.aquaq.co.uk/q/kdb-websockets/) an article about using websockets to connect the web browser and kdb+. You can use a similar method to connect node to kdb.

Answer (score 2):

I found this after searching around for a while. I'm using it in production and it's quite a good wrap. https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-q